# Resize Image without Keeping Aspect Ratio

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, system.drawing

I need to resize an Image to a specific size without taking into account the aspect ratio.This code takes into account aspect ratio.How can I ignore aspect ratio and do hard resize.

```
public Image resizeImage(int newWidth, int newHeight, string stPhotoPath)
 {
     Image imgPhoto = Image.FromFile(stPhotoPath); 

     int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
     int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;

     //Consider vertical pics
    if (sourceWidth < sourceHeight)
    {
        int buff = newWidth;

        newWidth = newHeight;
        newHeight = buff;
    }

    int sourceX = 0, sourceY = 0, destX = 0, destY = 0;
    float nPercent = 0, nPercentW = 0, nPercentH = 0;

    nPercentW = ((float)newWidth / (float)sourceWidth);
    nPercentH = ((float)newHeight / (float)sourceHeight);
    if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
    {
        nPercent = nPercentH;
        destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((newWidth -
                  (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        nPercent = nPercentW;
        destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((newHeight -
                  (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
    }

    int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
    int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);


    Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight,
                  PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution,
                 imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

    Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
    grPhoto.Clear(Color.Black);
    grPhoto.InterpolationMode =
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
        new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
        new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    grPhoto.Dispose();
    imgPhoto.Dispose();
    return bmPhoto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all the calculations and use

```
grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
    new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight),
    new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Here is the whole method:

```
public static Image Resize(Image source, int width, int height)
{
    if (source.Width == width && source.Height == height) return source;
    var result = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    result.SetResolution(source.HorizontalResolution, source.VerticalResolution);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sure. Do you need a path like above, or just `Image`?

Comment: I would prefer a method with Bitmap return type and 3 parameters source,width,height..

Comment: You can also use this signature [`Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Rectangle)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yws82c40(v=vs.110).aspx) which draws the image scaled to the dimensions of the specified destination rectangle.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Hi, good to see you around! Sure there are a couple overloads that can used, and w/o that resolution thing even a simple `Bitmap` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/334ey5b7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help @IvanStoev this works perfect :)